# C# Store a generic list parameter as a instance scope variable

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, types, casting, scope

I have the following method:

```
public void SetList<T>(IList<T> listINeedToStore)
{
    //Store the list in instance level scope
}
```

I would like to take the `listINeedToStore` parameter and store it in a private variable but I have failed to find a way. I tried to do something like `private IList<object> _tempVariable;` and then set `_tempVariable` to the `listINeedToStore` variable so I can use it later to remove or add items to it. I would set the list like `_tempVariable = (IList<object>)listINeedToStore;`. This does not work and will not compile. Something I should note is that T is a type of Enum.

I am sure there is a way to do this but I do not know it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a generic way without making the *type* generic instead of the *method*, basically. You can store the reference, but it would have to be via a field of a non-generic type, e.g. `IEnumerable` or even just `object`. To really use the list, you'd have to fetch it again with a generic method, and cast. For example:

```
private object list;

public void SetList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    this.list = list;
}

public List<T> GetList<T>()
{
    return (List<T>) list;
}
```

The fetch will fail at execution time if you specify the wrong type argument, of course.

I'd try to avoid this design if possible, but if you *really* need to do it, it will work. It just adds the burden of getting the type right to all the callers.

Note that if you change the parameter from `IList<T>` to `List<T>`, you could then store it in an `IList` (non-generic) which could be slightly more useful - but which would restrict the circumstances in which you could call the method, of course.